# Eclipse not supporting for dynamic web project using jdk10

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have downloaded eclipse sdk for jdk 10. its working for java 10 programs but if i want create any dynamic web project or i want create servlet or want to create or edit JSP file its not showing in eclipse show view.
Can you guys please guide.[no server or dynamic project or JSP is diplaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb86D.png)

Comment: Consider reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

From the [Eclipse Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/phoenix/webtools/) page:

> WTP 3.9.3a is planned for mid-April, as part of Oxygen.3a and its
>   support for this week's GA release of Java 10.

Whilst it doesn't explicitly say anything about WTP support for Java 10 there, I wouldn't expect it to be available in Dynamic Web Projects etc... before then.